# Can i use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql

Hello and have a good time.

I have such query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS SUBSTRING(color, 1, 3) as color FROM colors WHERE color LIKE '$color%' AND ottenok LIKE '$ottenok%';
```

And after it:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

for getting all records, like it has no DISTINCT. But after SELECT FOUND_ROWS() i am getting only unique records.

Have not found in search engines information about using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with  DISTINCT. So i am looking for advice, how can i edit my query to have an ability to get both massives - unique, and non-unique.

p.s. of course, i know that i can remove "distinct" from my query, and get a unique list AFTER my sql query, using php function array_unique(), but this does not suite me, i need to solve this task using only sql...

Comment: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` merely retrieves a value that was calculated in the previous query. It doesn't launch a new query, let alone a totally different one.

Answer (score 0):

In short: `found_rows()` will not get you the count without `distinct`, you need to count those records separately.

Background: as mysql documentation on [found_rows()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) says (emphasis is mine):

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is **desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned without the LIMIT**, but without running the statement again. To obtain this row count, include an SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

So, this technique simply allows you to get the count, had no limit been applied to the same statement. `Distinct` modifier is applied before `limit`, therefore this technique cannot be used to get the count without distinct.

You can use a separate `count(*)` query without any `distinct` modifier to get the desired count.